# Restkit: How to define relationships for JSON object with dynamic keys?

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have a JSON object with dynamic keys something like

carBrands:

{
13950: {
brand_id: "13950",
name: "Toyota",
country: "Japan",
retailer: ""
},
13633: {
brand_id: "13633",
name: "NISSAN",
country: "JAPAN",
retailer: ""
}
}

This need to be mapped with a normal JSON object.

cars:

{
{id: "xyz"
brand_id: "13950",
status: "pending",
user_id: "user1"
},
{id: "ABC",
brand_id: “13633”,
status: "Delivered",
user_id: "user2"
}
}

Here is the code for the carBrands object.

```
RKEntityMapping *carBrandsMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"CarBrands" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];    
carBrandsMapping.forceCollectionMapping = YES;    
[ carBrandsMapping addAttributeMappingFromKeyOfRepresentationToAttribute:@"brand_id"];    
carBrandsMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"brand_id"];    
[ carBrandsMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"(brand_id).name": @"name",    
@"(brand_id).retailer": @"retailer",    
@"(brand_id).country":@"country"    
}];

RKResponseDescriptor *brandsRD = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:carBrandsMapping method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:nil keyPath:@”brands” statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

For the cars object,

```
RKEntityMapping *carsMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Cars" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];    
carsMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"car_id"];   
[carsMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"id": @"car_id",    
@"brand_id": @"brand_id",    
@"status": @"status",    
@"user_id": @"user_id"    
}];

RKResponseDescriptor *carsRD = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:carsMapping method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:nil keyPath:@”cars” statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

I tried the following statements for defining relationships.

```
[carsMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"carBrands" connectedBy:@"brand_id"];

[carsMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"carBrands" toKeyPath:@"carsBrands" withMapping:brandsMapping]];
```

My problem is when I fetch the 'Car' data using following statements, my relationship object 'carBrands' is nil. I also got the 'found unmappable content' error. How to resolve it?

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:PATH_FOR_CAR parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {    
self.carsArray = mappingResult.array;
NSLog(@"%@",mappingResult.array);
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
RKLogError(@"Load failed with error: %@", error);
}];
```

Question:

How to define the relationship mapping, so that fetching 'Cars' entity will have the realtionship data 'carBrands' stored as faults and not nil?

```
@class CarBrands;    
@interface Cars: NSManagedObject    
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * car_id;    
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * brand_id;    
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * status;    
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * user_id;    
@property (nonatomic, retain) CarBrands *carBrands;    
@end
```

Thank you.

Comment: Who down-voted, and why?

Comment: You're calling to get the brands first, then when complete you call to get (and connect) cars? Using addConnectionForRelationship should be good. Have you turned on trace logging? Is the relationship in the model 1:many?

Comment: No, we're trying to get the cars first, and then want restkit to get the brands for us, based on the specified relationship. 1 brand to many cars.

Comment: Trace logging is on, yes, and that gives us messages like "Found unmappable value at keyPath: carBrands"

Comment: RestKit won't automatically go and get data for you, you need to request it and then RestKit will map (and connect) it into your data store.

Comment: Sorry, misspoke. Not that Restkit will automatically go and get data for us by following relationships, but in another project, we found that Restkit would indicate the completed mapping (of something like cars) with <fault> for the property carBrands. Then when we referred to myCar.carBrands (where myCar is an instance of Cars), it would go and get that car brand. In the current one, we're getting <nil> for the property carBrands. I guess we can just go try requesting restkit to load the carBrands separately

Comment: The car brands need to be loaded first for your current mapping to work. It may be possible to use more response descriptors to produce stub objects for brands from the car response and connect to those (but I haven't tried it recently and I'm sure I've read that it doesn't work now).